# What's happened to com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-pgp?

Tags: scala, sbt

I've been using [spray-swagger](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.gettyimages/spray-swagger_2.10/0.3.1) which has a dependency on [com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-pgp](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-pgp), and my builds suddenly started failing saying that this dependency couldn't be resolved. As you'll see if you click that link, it just returns a 404 error.

It seems odd that this has just been deleted... anybody know what's happened to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this "fresh" [workaround](http://github.com/gettyimages/spray-swagger/issues/16) can help you (the last post).

It seems to be a "bug/TODO" that needs to be fixed, as it is said in it:

> ... and artifact "com.typesafe.sbt", "sbt-pgp_2.10", "0.8.3" cannot
>   easily be found. It should only be a build dependency, not runtime
>   depedency.

Apparently, currently (before a patch), you have to exclude SBT-PGP from downloaded dependencies group:

```
"com.gettyimages" % "spray-swagger_2.10" % "0.3.1" exclude ("com.typesafe.sbt", "sbt-pgp")
```

Comment: Cool cheers, I'd looked at the bug list but somehow entirely failed to find that one... doh! Seems to be a good workaround for now.